# Using boto to enumerate EC2 reservations & expiration dates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I'd like to use boto to query our EC2 reservations and notify us when existing reservations are about to expire but I'm unable to figure out how to do this. The only data type related to reservations that appears to contain a date is the [boto.ec2.reservedinstance.ReservedInstanceListing](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html?highlight=boto.ec2.reservedinstance.reservedinstancelisting#boto.ec2.reservedinstance.ReservedInstanceListing) class, which is apparently only used to create a listing in the reservation marketplace. How can I determine through boto that a reservation is due to expire, say in the next 30 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly, it doesn't appear that you can.  The `DescribeReservedInstances` request for `EC2` allows you to filter the responses returned based on `start-time` or `end-time` of the reservation but the actual date the reservation was purchased is not returned in the response.  Very strange.  If the service doesn't return it, boto can't provide it.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I had assumed after staring at the boto docs for a while but I just wanted confirmation that I wasn't missing something...